# How can I add an image carousel in a Microsoft Team App manifest?

Tags: microsoft-teams

I need to add an image to a MS Teams App as part of the information display before the app is installed. Documentation does mention a carousel card but how can I put it on the app's manifest/info like the image below?[image: MS Team App with Carousel in the info display]

Comment: Did you find a way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

@Armando This is not part of the manifest. You can set this while submitting your app to the app store. Please reach out to teamsubmATmicrosoft.com for any further queries on this.